# Nullpointer when updating JCombobox

Tags: java, swing, jcombobox

I have been struggling with this for a time. I'm trying to update an empty JCombobox with an object of owner, as soon as it has been created by a click of a button, but i keep getting a nullpointerexception

```
        package gui;

    import java.awt.BorderLayout;
    import java.awt.EventQueue;

    import javax.swing.JFrame;
    import javax.swing.JPanel;
    import javax.swing.border.EmptyBorder;
    import javax.swing.JMenuBar;
    import javax.swing.JToolBar;
    import javax.swing.JTabbedPane;
    import javax.swing.JDesktopPane;
    import javax.swing.border.TitledBorder;
    import javax.swing.border.LineBorder;
    import java.awt.Color;
    import javax.swing.JLabel;
    import javax.swing.JTextField;
    import javax.swing.JButton;
    import java.awt.Insets;
    import java.awt.Button;
    import java.awt.Component;
    import javax.swing.JLayeredPane;
    import javax.swing.JTable;
    import javax.swing.Box;
    import javax.swing.JSplitPane;
    import javax.swing.AbstractAction;
    import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
    import javax.swing.Action;
    import javax.swing.JInternalFrame;
    import java.awt.event.*; 
    import controller.ForestOwnerCtr;


    import model.OwnerCon;
    import model.Owner;
    import model.Tree;

    import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import javax.swing.JList;
    import javax.swing.JComboBox;
    import java.awt.Choice;
    import java.awt.Label;
    import javax.swing.DefaultComboBoxModel;

    public class ForestGui extends JFrame {

        private static ForestOwnerCtr FOCtr;
        private JPanel contentPane;
        private JTextField txtOwnerName;
        private JTextField txtOwnerAdress;
        private JTextField txtOwnerPhone;
        private JTextField txtName;
        private JTextField txtLocation;
        private JTextField txtArea;
        private JTextField textField;
        private JTextField textField_3;
        private JTextField textField_4;
        private JTextField txtAge;
        private JComboBox<Owner> owner_select;
        private ArrayList<Owner> test;

        /**
         * Launch the application.
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    try {
                        ForestGui frame = new ForestGui();
                        frame.setVisible(true);
                    } catch (Exception e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }
            });
            FOCtr = new ForestOwnerCtr();
        }

        /**
         * Create the frame.
         */
        public ForestGui() {
            setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
            setBounds(100, 100, 946, 509);

            JMenuBar menuBar = new JMenuBar();
            setJMenuBar(menuBar);

            JButton btnCreate = new JButton("Create");
            menuBar.add(btnCreate);

            JButton btnSearch_1 = new JButton("Search");
            menuBar.add(btnSearch_1);
            contentPane = new JPanel();
            contentPane.setBorder(new EmptyBorder(5, 5, 5, 5));
            setContentPane(contentPane);
            contentPane.setLayout(null);

            JPanel panel_search_forest = new JPanel();
            panel_search_forest.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(130, 135, 144)), "Seach forest", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
            panel_search_forest.setToolTipText("tst");
            panel_search_forest.setBounds(15, 11, 238, 238);
            contentPane.add(panel_search_forest);
            panel_search_forest.setLayout(null);

            JLabel lblName_1 = new JLabel("Name");
            lblName_1.setBounds(10, 28, 46, 14);
            panel_search_forest.add(lblName_1);

            txtName = new JTextField();
            txtName.setColumns(10);
            txtName.setBounds(92, 26, 119, 19);
            panel_search_forest.add(txtName);

            JLabel lblLocation = new JLabel("Location");
            lblLocation.setBounds(10, 56, 58, 14);
            panel_search_forest.add(lblLocation);

            JLabel lblArea = new JLabel("Area");
            lblArea.setBounds(10, 81, 46, 14);
            panel_search_forest.add(lblArea);

            txtLocation = new JTextField();
            txtLocation.setColumns(10);
            txtLocation.setBounds(92, 54, 119, 19);
            panel_search_forest.add(txtLocation);

            txtArea = new JTextField();
            txtArea.setColumns(10);
            txtArea.setBounds(92, 79, 119, 19);
            panel_search_forest.add(txtArea);

            JLabel lblAge = new JLabel("Age");
            lblAge.setBounds(10, 106, 46, 14);
            panel_search_forest.add(lblAge);

            txtAge = new JTextField();
            txtAge.setColumns(10);
            txtAge.setBounds(92, 107, 119, 19);
            panel_search_forest.add(txtAge);

            JButton CreateForest = new JButton("New forest");
            CreateForest.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent arg0) {
                    createForest();
                }
            });
            CreateForest.setBounds(109, 204, 119, 23);
            panel_search_forest.add(CreateForest);

            JLabel lblOwner = new JLabel("Owner");
            lblOwner.setBounds(10, 131, 46, 14);
            panel_search_forest.add(lblOwner);

            Choice choice = new Choice();
            choice.setBounds(92, 163, 119, 19);
            panel_search_forest.add(choice);

            JLabel lblTreeSorts = new JLabel("Tree sorts");
            lblTreeSorts.setBounds(10, 163, 76, 20);
            panel_search_forest.add(lblTreeSorts);


            JComboBox<Owner> owner_select = new JComboBox<Owner>();
            owner_select.setModel(new DefaultComboBoxModel(FOCtr.getOwners().toArray()));
            owner_select.setBounds(90, 137, 121, 20);

            panel_search_forest.add(owner_select);




            JPanel searc_owner = new JPanel();
            searc_owner.setToolTipText("tst");
            searc_owner.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(130, 135, 144)), "Seach owner", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
            searc_owner.setBounds(263, 11, 250, 196);
            contentPane.add(searc_owner);
            searc_owner.setLayout(null);

            JLabel lblName = new JLabel("Name");
            lblName.setBounds(10, 22, 46, 14);
            searc_owner.add(lblName);

            JLabel lblAdress = new JLabel("Adress");
            lblAdress.setBounds(10, 47, 46, 14);
            searc_owner.add(lblAdress);

            JLabel lblPhoneNumber = new JLabel("Phone number");
            lblPhoneNumber.setBounds(10, 77, 83, 14);
            searc_owner.add(lblPhoneNumber);

            txtOwnerName = new JTextField();
            txtOwnerName.setBounds(111, 20, 119, 17);
            searc_owner.add(txtOwnerName);
            txtOwnerName.setColumns(10);

            txtOwnerAdress = new JTextField();
            txtOwnerAdress.setColumns(10);
            txtOwnerAdress.setBounds(111, 45, 119, 17);
            searc_owner.add(txtOwnerAdress);

            txtOwnerPhone = new JTextField();
            txtOwnerPhone.setColumns(10);
            txtOwnerPhone.setBounds(111, 75, 119, 17);
            searc_owner.add(txtOwnerPhone);

            JButton btnSearch = new JButton("New Owner");
            btnSearch.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
                public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent E) {
                    createOwner();
                }
            });



            btnSearch.setBounds(141, 162, 89, 23);
            searc_owner.add(btnSearch);



            JPanel panel = new JPanel();
            panel.setLayout(null);
            panel.setToolTipText("tst");
            panel.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new LineBorder(new Color(130, 135, 144)), "Seach forest", TitledBorder.LEADING, TitledBorder.TOP, null, null));
            panel.setBounds(585, 171, 238, 196);
            contentPane.add(panel);

            JLabel label = new JLabel("Name");
            label.setBounds(10, 28, 46, 14);
            panel.add(label);

            textField = new JTextField();
            textField.setColumns(10);
            textField.setBounds(78, 25, 119, 17);
            panel.add(textField);

            JLabel label_1 = new JLabel("Location");
            label_1.setBounds(10, 56, 58, 14);
            panel.add(label_1);

            JLabel label_2 = new JLabel("Area");
            label_2.setBounds(10, 81, 46, 14);
            panel.add(label_2);

            textField_3 = new JTextField();
            textField_3.setColumns(10);
            textField_3.setBounds(78, 53, 119, 17);
            panel.add(textField_3);

            textField_4 = new JTextField();
            textField_4.setColumns(10);
            textField_4.setBounds(78, 78, 119, 17);
            panel.add(textField_4);

            JButton button_1 = new JButton("Search");
            button_1.setBounds(139, 162, 89, 23);
            panel.add(button_1);


            }






    private void createForest(){

        String name = txtName.getText();
        String location = txtLocation.getText();
        int totalArea = Integer.parseInt(txtArea.getText());
        int age = Integer.parseInt(txtAge.getText());
        //Owner owner = 
        FOCtr.createForest(name, location, totalArea, age);
        }

   private void createOwner(){


        String newName = txtOwnerName.getText();
        String newAdress = txtOwnerAdress.getText();
        String newPhone = txtOwnerPhone.getText();
        Owner o = new Owner(newName, newAdress, newPhone);
        test.add(o);
        owner_select.addItem(o);
        }

    }

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at gui.ForestGui.createOwner(ForestGui.java:285)
    at gui.ForestGui.access$1(ForestGui.java:278)
    at gui.ForestGui$3.actionPerformed(ForestGui.java:211)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.AbstractButton$Handler.actionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.fireActionPerformed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.DefaultButtonModel.setPressed(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicButtonListener.mouseReleased(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at javax.swing.JComponent.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.processEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.retargetMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.processMouseEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.LightweightDispatcher.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Container.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Window.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.Component.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$200(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$3.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$4.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.ProtectionDomain$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: At what line do you get the exception?

Comment: That is WAY too much code! Please post a [SSCCE (link)](http://sscce.org). Also, I think `import javax.swing.*` would be helpful... :O

Comment: Please tell us what line you get the exception, plus post the stack trace.

Comment: The nullpointerexception only comes when i acctually call the line with
        owner_select.addItem(o);

I have been eliminating everything else.

Answer (score 2):

```
I have been struggling with this for a time
```

Fixing this shouldn't take more than five minutes.

NPE is the easiest problem of all to solve.  Print the stack trace, note the class and line number at which it occurs, and scan that line for references that you didn't initialize by setting them equal to a non-null reference.  Use an IDE with a debugger if it's not obvious.

Just don't make the mistake of repeating the same behavior and expecting a different result.  Unless it's a race condition that's causing your problem, that's one sign of insanity.

FWIW, you're writing too much code.  That's one reason why I hate Swing - too much code!  A little thought and decomposition will go a long way.

For instance, there's no reason on earth for your class to extend `JFrame`.  `JPanel` would be a better choice.  You can embed your class in a `JFrame` and off you go.

`textField_4`?  What's that?  How can anyone tell what that's for?  The mystified individual might even be you three weeks from now.

Answer (score 2):

You define a class variable that is null:

```
private JComboBox<Owner> owner_select;
```

Then you create a local variable that is not null in your constructor:

```
JComboBox<Owner> owner_select = new JComboBox<Owner>();
```

The code in your createOwner() method can only access the class variable. You don't want to create a local variable so the code in the constructor should be:

```
owner_select = new JComboBox<Owner>();
```